# Join grease pencil to object

Tags: grease-pencil

I am using 2.82 (via snap on OpenSuse Linux).

I can draw via grease pencil (an annotation) onto the side of a cube using "surface", but, if I move the cube the drawing doesn't move.

How do I join the cube and the strokes?

Comment: you're using anotation when you should be using a grease pencil object, then parent that object to your cube

Comment: Thanks that helped a bit.I did:                    start with standard scene
add Grease Pencil Blank 
go to "Object Properties/Relations"
Select "Cube" for the Parent
Change to "Draw" mode
In "Origin" tab select "surface"
draw something on a face of the cube
Go back to "Object" mode
Everything works fine:
the drawing is on the surface
moving the cube also moves the strokes I drew
Problem now: how do I change the color of the strokes.
By default the color is a light grey. My painting is 
only visible by tilting the cube slightly.

Comment: Glad that helped. GP is a vast subject, and blender keeps on changing. I warmly recommend you watch this, it'll give you some good basics https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9N-glGarYuM

Comment: Many thanks. I worked through the tutorial video you pointed out. This was very instructive.  May I ask another questions? Is there anything like tweening in Blender?

Comment: kinda, in edit mode there's the `Interpolate` menu (top left) but it only works well if the drawings are copies modified with sculpt/rotate/resize